# Delphi 5 - SQL Functions + Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 tmemofield

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I'm using a TADOQuery which is connected to an Access database with the **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** provider.

With the request : "**SELECT TRIM(FIELD_NAME) AS C FROM TABLE_NAME**", C is a TMemoField.

If I change the provider to **Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0**, the field "**C**" is a TStringField.

I've noticed that when i'm using the Microsoft.ACE, all of the SQL functions return a TMemoField !

Considering the amount of code, I can't review all of the requests. Is there a solution, by using a Microsoft.ACE provider, i should be able to retrieve a TStringField when i'm using a function in my request ? A parameter in the connection string for example ?

Thanks

Comment: What amount of code are you talking about and all of what requests can't you review? " i should be able to retrieve a TStringField"  Not necessarily, it sounds like the TAdoQuery thinks it is dealing with a variety of blob field.

Comment: Would it be a good practice to stick with one Provider/driver and if you are going to accept more than one driver then profile it. Aka, have overriding functions native to the selected provider/driver?

Comment: @MartynA : 1 500 000 lines